# Convert JSP to HTML

Tags: java, jsp

Is there any way to convert a jsp file to html?
The goal is that the jsp files have a lots of tags, and the real time parsing is too slow, so we want to generate simple statis html files that easy and fast to serve.

In my mind, when the server starts, something generates the static html files, and we only refer to these files in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Jsp files run on the server . It is the server side technology to render views .the main advantage of jsp over html is ,

1. It supports jstl and EL
2. Can embed java codes through `servlets`

> The goal is that the jsp files have a lots of tags

Jsp doesnt have any special tags as you mentioned , supports all html tags

> Is there any way to convert a jsp file to html?

**JSP is a server-side scripting language, whereas HTML is a client-side scripting language.** So how do you expect this to be done.

> simple static html files that easy and fast to serve

**HTML loads faster as it runs on the local machine. JSP takes some time to load as it has to interact with Web Server.**

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Its not about expectations... We just have a very simple workflow (where the jsp is just one thing), and we want to improve the production. Yes, jsp is a server side language, and it generates HTML when the client requested via the webserver. We just want to skip that step, and want to generate the html at the server start instead of "on the fly". Yes, this is not the best way we should do, but there is no more option

Comment: Yes you could use the plain html if you wish to ignore the functionality of jsp. that could increase the processing speed at the server

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (if the JSP pages are static) is to initiate a http connection to your server and access the page source code in the final product. This won't work however if your page isn't static as the content will change.

Really it doesn't make sense to use JSP pages for static content but if your content is not static then you should see why the pages are being loaded slowly. Maybe the way you are linking the dynamic data to the JSP pages or retrieving the information isn't being done well.